# Relative path to connect to ms accdb

Tags: java, database, ms-access, ucanaccess

I'm using NetBeans and this is my project folder:

[image]

My executable is in the 'dist' folder. About the code,in my connection class I used the following string:

```
"jdbc:ucanaccess://.\\mydb.accdb"
```

So i used a relative path from dist folder.
This works the first time i execute the program and correctly connect to database, but the next times i have the following exception:

```
"given file does not exist: .\mydb.accdb"
```

Obviously the file exists and it works the first time as i wrote. I'm also sure i'm doing something wrong. Can someone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've solved. I was using a relative path starting from the dist folder while I had to use a relative path from the folder where is the connection class.